# My function factoring program has problems with variables, shows incorrect answers

Tags: c++

I'm making a program that factors functions (f(x), not fully factored though):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdio.h>

using namespace std;
int x3;
int x2;
int x;
int remain;
int r = 0;
int factor;

int main() {

  int b, i, j = 0;
  int factors[101];

  cout << "f(x) = x^3 + x^2 + x + r (Factor tool)" << endl;
  cout << "x^3?: ";
  cin >> x3;
  cout << "x^2: ";
  cin >> x2;
  cout << "x: ";
  cin >> x;

  printf("remain  (Y intercept): ");
  scanf("%d", &b);
  cout << "f(x) = " << x3 << "x^3 + " << x2 << "x^2 + " << x << "x + " << b
       << "" << endl;

  cout << "factors of remainder are: " << endl;
  for (i = 1; i <= b; i++) {
    if (b % i == 0) {
      factors[j++] = i;
      printf("%d\t", i);
    }
  }
  getchar();

  while (true) {
    int good;

    if (factors[1] == 0) {
      cout <<endl;
      cout << "Equation Cannot be factored";
      break;
    }
    int factorv = factors[r];
    int nx1 = x3 * factors[r];
    int nx2 = (nx1 + x2);
    int nx3 = x + (nx2 * factors[r]);
    int nx4 = remain + (nx3 * factors[r]);

    if (nx4 == 0) {
      int factored = (0 - factors[r]);
       cout <<endl;
       cout << "The Factored Function: f(x) = "
           << "(x " << factored << ")(" << nx1 << "x^3 + " << nx2 << "x^2 + "
           << nx3 << "x"
           << ")"
           << "";
      break;

    } else {
      r = r + 1;
    }
  }
}
```

but in this part of the code, it shows as (x 0)(0x^3 + (x3 input instead of calculated nx1)x^2 + (x2 input instead of calculated nx2)x).

```
 if (nx4 == 0) {
    int factored = (0-factors[r]);
    cout<<"The Factored Function: f(x) = "<<"(x "<<factored<<")("<<nx1<<"x^3 + "<<nx2<<"x^2 + "<<nx3<<"x"<<")"<<"";
    break;
```

What happen to my nx variables? Why is it coming up incorrect or as a 0 when it was calculated properly above?

Comment: You have multiple "nx1" variables, "nx2" variables, etc.  Look at your code carefully.  So ask yourself what happens when you declare `int nx1` (for example), multiple times.  Which one is being used at which time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have some of your variables twice:

```
int nx1;
int nx2;
int nx3;
int nx4;
```

They exists as global variables and again in the scope of `main`. They have the same name but are different variables.

Take the lesson: Global variables are no good.

Moreover you have a logic error in your code. When I add a `std::cout << r << std::endl;` in the last `while` loop I see its value increasing until there is a segfault, because `factors[r]` is out-of-bounds. [broken code @ wandbox](https://wandbox.org/permlink/PlLNBElX2ic9Zici)

I cannot really tell you how to fix it, because I would have to dive into the maths first. I can only suggest you to **never** use infinte loops in numerical codes without an "emergency exit". What i mean is that unless fully tested, you cannot be sure that the loop will end at some point and when it doesn't typically the consequences are bad and difficult to diagnose. Always make sure the loop will end at some point:

```
int max_iteratons = 100;
int counter;
while (counter < max_iteratons) {
    // do something
    ++counter;
}
if (counter == max_iterations) std::cout << "i have a bug :(";
```

Comment: Still if I remove these, same problem appears and I only put them there to remind myself of the varibles.

Comment: @RidwanAlam what is the input? when I remove the globals and then add the variables missing in `main` I get output that looks more or less ok-ish: https://wandbox.org/permlink/PorbNEeL1Y6ThlAE

Comment: x^3 = 1 
x^2 = 1
x = -8
remainder = 10



should be (x -2)(1x^3 +2x^2 + -6x)

Comment: @RidwanAlam so your input is `1 1` ? The program expects more input

Comment: no the third comment is the corrrect input. I was editing my comment disregard the old revision of the comment.

Comment: The equation that cannot be factored works as usual (says it cannot be factored). But if it can be factored, it doesn't show the correct answer.

Comment: @RidwanAlam see edit. there is another problem in your code, related to `r` increasing more than `factors` has elements

Comment: I just did it in Python and it seems to work fine, but whatever